Next Js solely for api calls
I have a react front end and a .net backend. I want to use next js for data fetching and updating between the front end and backend. Is this a good practice. Are there any advantages to doing this? And if so how should I get started. I am pretty new to Next js.

Are you trying to use Next.js as an intermediary stage between the React frontend and the .NET backend? If so, that is completely unnecessary. Regular HTTP calls using fetch or axios from the React frontend should do the job. However, if you React frontend is part of the larger Next.js project, you can look into Next.js Fetching Docs for more information on what best suits your use case. Personally, I like to fetch data the way Google does it: basic user data is SSR'd and then app-specific data is rendered on the client side.
